# How to get tier 2 friends or "people I may know" from Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook API, how would I go about finding people on Facebook, that are friends with a lot of my friends.

You see it in the sidebar as People You May Know, and it shows some people that are friends with a lot of your friends. Like: "Do you know John Smith? 65 mutual friends".

How do I generate a list of say 100 of these top tier-2 friends that have also authorized my app?

Comment: that kind of data is not available with the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way it would work is if you stored your users friend lists, all of your friends used your application and all of their friends used your application.  You can only retrieve a list of current friends who use your application.  If (somehow) you managed to fulfill the requirements I stated, however; you could simply compare the friend lists you've stored to one another and see which friends are not on your list but are on others.  It's not exactly feasible, though, because every one of them would need to authorize your application.

Comment: you would have to update the friendlists after every user authorization too